# Plotting an Infinite series question

Tags: plotting

I am trying to plot the infinite sum:

$$u(x,t)=∑_{n=1}(8L^2/(2n-1)^3π^3)\sin(((2n-1)πx)/L)e^{(-(2n-1)^2π^2kt)/L^2}$$

with $L=1$, $k=1$ and $t=0.1$, $0.2$, $0.5$, $1.0$, $10.0$.

This is what I have tried:

```
L = 1;
k = 1;

f[x_, t_, nm_] = 
 Sum[(8 L^2/((2 n - 1)^3*Pi^3))*(sin(((2n-1)*Pi*x)/
       L)) e^((-(2 n - 1)^2*Pi^2*k*t)/L^2), {n, 1, nm}]; 

Plot[Table[f[x, t, 150], {t, {0.1, 0.2, 0.5, 1.0, 10.0}}] // Release, {x, 
      0, 10}]
```

However, I always end up with an empty plot when *Mathematica* has finished 
calculating.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Yep, I just tried that and it fixed my problems. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I am sorry for not trying before giving an answer, but right now I don't have access to Mathematica.

```
step=0.1;

ListPointPlot3D[Table[{x,t, f[x, t, 150]}, {t, {0.1, 0.2, 0.5, 1.0, 10.0}},{x,0,10,step}]
```

Update: You have syntax error. Turn the sines into Sin[], "e"s into "E"s and so on.

Comment: That fixed my problems! Thank you so much! I love syntax errors.